# How can I remove the black status bar over PPRevealSideViewController?

Tags: ios

I have a PPRevealSideViewController and when is being called appears the status bar on top of view.

[image: black stripe]

I initialize it in appDelegate.m like this:

```
MainViewController *main = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:main];

_revealSideViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nav];

_revealSideViewController.delegate = self;

self.window.rootViewController = _revealSideViewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Could anyone tell me how can I make this disappear, or make it the color of background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.
You have two options (fading is set as default). `PPRevealSideOptionsiOS7StatusBarFading` and `PPRevealSideOptionsiOS7StatusBarMoving`.
And you can change the color of status bar like this:

```
    [self.revealSideViewController setFakeiOS7StatusBarColor:<#(UIColor *)#>];
```